# Daylight javascript formatting date

Tags: javascript, date, formatting, dst

I have this problem.
I have this date with this format

```
var datestring = "2017-10-30T15:03:10.933044Z";
```

If I write my code like this

```
var d = new Date(datestring);
```

I obtaine

```
Mon Oct 30 2017 16:03:10 GMT+0100 (ora solare Europa occidentale)
```

because there is one hour of a daylight in italy now. Nevertheless, I would like to have the same hour of 'datestring' (15, and not 16).
Could you help me?

thank you very much

Comment: Have you tried solving this with external library like `moment.js`?

Comment: nope, but I suppose that the solution proposed by @Connum it's enough, don't you believe?

Comment: His answer wasn't there, when I was commenting)
For me his snippet prints `"2017-10-30T13:03:10.933Z"`

Comment: Do you mean you want to treat a UTC timestamp as local?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to ECMA-262, if you want to treat an ISO 8601 format UTC timestamp as local, just remove the Z. However, it will now represent a different moment in time if the local timezone is not GMT+0000.

Also, using the built-in parser is not recommended (see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)), as some browsers will still treat it as UTC (e.g. Safari 11) or perhaps invalid. You should either write your own function to parse the string, or use a library. There are plenty of good parsing and formatting libraries available.

```js
var s = '2017-10-30T15:03:10.933044Z';
var d = new Date(s.replace(/z/i,''));
console.log(d.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input string is in ISO-8601 format.  In this format, the `Z` at the end means the timestamp is UTC-based.

You can obtain a more human-friendly UTC-based string representation with the `.toUTCString()` method.

```
var datestring = "2017-10-30T15:03:10.933044Z";
var d = new Date(datestring);
var s = d.toUTCString();
console.log(s) // "Mon, 30 Oct 2017 15:03:10 GMT"
```

If you want the string in a specific format, then consider using a library like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).